# Learning resources - Any good websites for learning about quantitative finance with a focus on the underlying mathematics?

Tags: finance-mathematics, statistics, resource, learning

Typically when I have ventured into a new subject in my sparetime, I have been able to find an interactive website with reading materials, exercises and the like. To name a few there is https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/ and https://runestone.academy/ns/books/published/FOPP-PIE/index.html?mode=browsing.

However, I do not know if any such sites exist for mathematical finance and quantatitve finance? I can find quite a few online courses, but they seem to be tailored more towards the applied end, whereas I am also very much interested in the fundamental and underlying mathematics, as I am thinking of pursuing my master's in this subject.

Please link to some good resources on the subject.

Comment: _Any good websites for learning about quantitative finance with a focus on the underlying mathematics?_  What about Quant.SE? :) [QuantPie](https://quantpie.co.uk/)  (and its [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/c/quantpie) channel) from @[Magic is in the chain](https://quant.stackexchange.com/users/35546/magic-is-in-the-chain) is nice.